# How to take a merge replication back up?

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have a windows server 2012 with SQL Server 2012 configured with Merge replication with three subscribers.

I want to take a full back up the merge replication in case of total sql server crush. I am not sure how to take it or which databases to take a back up? for how long? so that if some thing happens then I will just restore all the configuration back.

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take backups of these databases

- The **publication** database at the Publisher
- The **distribution** database at the Distributor
- The **subscription** database at each Subscriber
- The **master** and **msdb** system databases at the Publisher, Distributor and all Subscribers. These databases should be backed up
  at the same time as each other and the relevant replication database.
  For example, back up the master and msdb databases at the Publisher
  at the same time you back up the publication database. If the
  publication database is restored, ensure that the master and msdb
  database are consistent with the publication database in terms of
  replication configuration and settings.

For more information, refer [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152497.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To add to what ughai posted, all replication components should be scripted out as a part of a disaster recovery plan.  They should also be rescripted if any publication and/or subscription property changes are made.

This is covered in the section ***Script the replication topology*** in [Best Practicies for Replication Administration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151818.aspx) and in [Scripting Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152483.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Guys!!  looking at the links you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like a need of a proper disaster recovery plan, from what you describe. You can create your own or maybe use a third party vendor in order to do that. We worked with cloudendure back at the time, I'm not sure as for their costs right now, maybe it's worth a look. What happens is that you've got a replica being formed and updated in 1 sec time intervals, replication of the data goes right onto the target location (the cloud), and we're aiming for near zero downtime so for whenever that happens, your replica will be loaded automatically onto your site.